# Did the updated module actually update?

Tags: updating

Just performed an update to Drupal 7.56. In the process I updated all modules, including Google Analytics. The weird thing is that on my machine, where I performed the update, Google Analytics updated just fine.

But, after placing the files onto the server, and updating the DB with a copy of my own, the server is saying Google Analytic is still in need of an update. Everything else appears fine.

I checked the files for the Google Analytics module, and they are indeed the updated version.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Cy

Comment: After you imported the DB, copy of your own, did you run `yourwebsite.com/update.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run **http://serversite.com/update.php**.

You may have forgotten to **clear the cache** before you download the Database you upload to the server.

Next Time try try to clear the cache before you export your database file. Also I will recommend you use [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) Plugin, that should be efficient in the future without error